# nativescript(Angular) - routing inside firebase event listener

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript, angular-routing

In nativescript(Angular), I'm using (nativescript-angular/router) and (nativescript-plugin-firebase)

when i write the code like that(the order page var binding not working):

```
firebase.addValueEventListener(result => {
    this.router.navigate(['/order'], { clearHistory:true });
}, path);
```

[and this is the simulator image of the order page when the code is inside the listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p8Wq.png)

but when the routing code is outside of the event listener it works

```
this.router.navigate(['/order'], { clearHistory:true });
firebase.addValueEventListener(result => {}, path);
```

[and this when the code is outside... the var value shows in the template perfectly fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWguM.png)

this is the template code ***order.html***

```
<Label [text]="test"></Label>
```

and this is ***order.component.ts***

```
export class OrderComponent  {
  public test = "test var value";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the navigation inside an Angular zoned callback.

```
import { Component, NgZone } from "@angular/core";

...

constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
}

firebase.addValueEventListener(result => {
     this.zone.run(() => {
         this.router.navigate(['/order'], { clearHistory:true });
     ])
}, path)
```

Comment: the zone fix was the right one although the promise isn't the right way to use the event listener but i put the zone code inside the event listener function and it worked! Thanks man.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. I am revising my answer to contain only the working solution. It seems that NativeScript application events and Firebase event listeners should be wrapped in an Angular zoned callback in order for the bindings to work as expected.